# How would I use a convolution for a colored image?

Tags: java, c, image, image-processing

To use a convolution for a one channel or greyscale image is pretty easy (just do some calculations with image pixels and kernels). But how it's done for a colored image? C or JAVA code is okay as examples.

Comment: Have you tried doing it per color-channel? That would be a better starting point ;)

Comment: @arynaq Would that work? :) I just asked because I am just curious, I am not implementing any application like this at the moment.

Comment: I have no idea, it would be something I would try first though. There is the human perception and sensitivity to the different colors to take into consideration though. I am equally curious to see examples with (hopefully) images so waiting for some answers.

Comment: If `is it much more difficult to do that for a colored image?` is the question, why is there talk about programming languages? Are you actually try to ask a different question?

Comment: I am actually asking for an implementation, or pseudo code, or theory, or something. I know how it's done for a one channel only.

Comment: You might want to amend your question to make what you are really after clearer

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you want to achieve:
A Gaussian kernel on all color channels can be used to achieve a blurring effect.

Translating the image to YUV, and working on the Y channel only can change the contrast of the image.

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried?

Depending on what kernel you want to use, it will often be straightforward:
many kernels will operate on split channels, so in fact you can process each channel independently.

But then of course there can be really messy kernels, too!